# How save only time in mysql with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to save only the time in my Database using Sequelize with node.js, I know how save datetimes but I don't know if this ORM supports the type field TIME that exists in MYSQL.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does support datatype `time`:

```
startTime: {type: DataTypes.TIME}
//or
startTime: {type: Sequelize.TIME}
```